# Is it possible to keep using my current apps and their data on a different iPod?

Tags: ipod-touch, upgrade

I have an iPod 5 but I want the front and back camera, so for my upcoming birthday in April I'm planning an upgrade.

Can I use the same Apple ID and start at the same level on the Apps I have on this iPod?

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a **backup**, but sync all applications first to your PC else you have to do extra work. Syncing to iCloud is possible, but if you want to restore all your applications back on the new iPod it's much **easier** to make an **iTunes** backup as you can sync back all applications on the new iPod.

If you make the backup Encrypted, it will also save all your passwords etc, making setting up of the new device much easier. [Don't forget the encryption password!]

Restore the backup you make from the current iPod on your new iPod!

Sync all apps back on and you're done - even the settings etc are now on your new iPod.

Comment: Be sure to "backup" not just "sync" ... you can backup to iCloud, but I believe backup to iTunes includes more stuff than backup to iCloud.

Comment: @GEdgar I did upgrade my post a little bit, but I said "Backup" already rather than "sync only"